# iOS: Long Touch Gesture

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit

[image]

I have these sizes of circles that changes using a UISlider and draws on touch.

Now, i am trying give it a new style on how it will draw on the screen on touch, and it's like this, when the user holds the touch (for example he's on the middle size circle) it'll start form the smallest size and stops on its current size but when the user just tap the screen very quick it'll just draw the smallest size no matter what's the size is...

how will i able to that??

here's my current code:
 On touchesBegan:

```
if(!touchSwiped) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [drawView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, color1, color2, color3, alpha);
        CGContextSetBlendMode(context, blendMode);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, endingPoint.x, endingPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, endingPoint.x, endingPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
        CGContextFlush(context);
        drawView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[`UILongPressGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) may be what you're looking for.